# gitlab run ci tests with django and postgres

Tags: django, gitlab-ci, docker-in-docker

I have managed to build image and compile and able to push the images to gitlab container registry. My next step is to use these images to run a test

When I try to run the djando app in docker it seems to fail with `The SECRET_KEY setting must not be empty.` but I can see it exists when I run export before docker run. see comments in the code below

```
unittests:
  stage: test
  before_script:
    - export IMAGE=$CI_REGISTRY/$CI_PROJECT_NAMESPACE/$CI_PROJECT_NAME
    - export WEB_IMAGE=$IMAGE/django
    - export DB_IMAGE=$IMAGE/postgres
  image: docker
  script:
    - docker login -u $CI_REGISTRY_USER -p $CI_JOB_TOKEN $CI_REGISTRY
    - docker pull registry.gitlab.com/domain/app/postgres:latest
    - ls -al
    - ./setup_env.sh # this will copy envvars to .env
    - export # I can see all the required envvars are set
    - docker run --env-file .env registry.gitlab.com/domain/app/django:latest bash -e SECRET_KEY=1 # this is failing to run with the error mentioned
    - docker ps
    - docker images
    - docker exec django robot tests
  only:
    refs:
      - merge_requests
    variables:
      - $CI_MERGE_REQUEST_TARGET_BRANCH_NAME == "qa"
```

dockerfile

```
FROM python:3.7-slim

RUN apt-get update
RUN apt-get install -y libpq-dev zip
RUN apt-get install gcc -y
# for chrome driver
RUN apt-get install -y libglib2.0-0 libnss3 libgconf-2-4 libfontconfig1 chromium-driver

COPY . /app
RUN chmod +x app/aws_start.sh
RUN chmod +x app/setup_env.sh
RUN pip install -r /app/dev-requirements.txt
RUN pip install gunicorn
VOLUME /app
WORKDIR /app
RUN bash /app/setup_env.sh
EXPOSE 4000

ENV PYTHONUNBUFFERED 1
RUN ["chmod", "+x", "/app/aws_start.sh"]
ENTRYPOINT /app/aws_start.sh
```

aws_start.sh

```
#!/bin/sh
./setup_env.sh
python manage.py migrate
python manage.py collectstatic --noinput
python manage.py create_default_superuser
gunicorn -w 3 -b :4000 app.wsgi:application &
```

setup_env.sh

```
#!/bin/sh

echo DEBUG=0 >> .env
echo SQL_ENGINE=django.db.backends.postgresql >> .env
echo DATABASE=postgres >> .env

echo SECRET_KEY=$SECRET_KEY >> .env
echo SQL_DATABASE=$SQL_DATABASE >> .env
echo SQL_USER=$SQL_USER >> .env
echo SQL_PASSWORD=$SQL_PASSWORD >> .env
echo SQL_HOST=$SQL_HOST >> .env
echo SQL_PORT=$SQL_PORT >> .env
echo WEB_IMAGE=$IMAGE:web  >> .env
echo NGINX_IMAGE=$IMAGE:nginx  >> .env
echo CI_REGISTRY_USER=$CI_REGISTRY_USER   >> .env
echo CI_JOB_TOKEN=$CI_JOB_TOKEN  >> .env
echo CI_REGISTRY=$CI_REGISTRY  >> .env
echo IMAGE=$CI_REGISTRY/$CI_PROJECT_NAMESPACE/$CI_PROJECT_NAME >> .env
echo AWS_ACCOUNT_ID=$AWS_ACCOUNT_ID >> .env
echo HOSTNAME=$HOSTNAME >> .env

# django
echo ALLOWED_HOSTS=$ALLOWED_HOSTS >> .env
echo BASE_URL=$BASE_URL >> .env
echo ENVIRONMENT=$ENVIRONMENT >> .env

# copy for docker
if [ -f "docker/.env_local" ]; then
  rm docker/.env_local
fi
cat .env >> docker/.env_local
```

Comment: Would you add the Dockerfile of the project, too?